# How to use the Python script in Matlab to call the variables which defined in Matlab workspace?

Tags: python, matlab, workspace

In Matlab, the variables can be simply defined, For example:

```
>>global x y
>>x = 1;
>>y = 2;
```

Then, I try to call this variables `x` and `y` in the pre-defined python script`f()`as:

```
def f():

    global x y
    return x + y
```

However, when I run this Python script in Matlab:

```
>>py.f.f
>>ans =
>>        0
```

It returns `0`, which the expected value should be `3`.

Comment: `global x y` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to refer to *Python* globals, or are you trying to refer to Matlab variables from Python?

Comment: Your functions are not equivalent.  In the Python function, you define `x` and `y` as `0`, but in matlab, you define them as `1` and `2`.

Comment: I am trying to pass the variables from matlab workspace to python function, and call this python function in matlab